# Не работает отправка формы на почту через phpMailer, почему?

Tags: php, phpmailer

Fetch запрос работает, статус 200. Все данные верные. Пароль 100% верный, логин, порт тоже верный. Но почему то на почту ничего не приходит(в спаме тоже ничего нет). Как думаете, в чём дело?

[image: php-скрипт. Он рабочий.]
[image: инфа про почту, на которую делаю отправку]
[image: feth запросы верные]

*до этого я вводил свою почту и свой логин +gmail-овский smtp. Всё приходило. То есть PHP файл рабочий, всё я что там поменял - это данные(пароль/логин/почту/smtp), но почему то теперь перестало работать..

Comment: Никогда не надо спрашивать, "почему у меня перестало работать?". По этим подслеповатым картинкам все равно никто вам не скажет. Спрашивать надо "как мне разобраться, почему не работает?". Для начала надо выкинуть все эти фантики и бантики. Fetch запрос участвует в отправке письма? **Зачем он здесь?** Консоль участвует в отправке письма? **Зачем она здесь?** При проблемах с отправкой, вы должны тестировать **только РНР код**, и ничего больше.

Answer (score 0):

Если код не работает, надо не разглядывать его с умилением, а **отлаживать**.

Для PHPMailer отладка заключается во включении вывода команд, которыми он обменивается с сервером. Это делается командой

```
 $mail->SMTPDebug = 2;
```

то есть надо взять свой код, добавить к нему эту команду перед send(), запустить, и смотреть лог общения с сервером, который он выводит. Выведенные ошибки либо самостоятельно осмыслить, либо гуглить.

Answer (score 0):

С вероятностью в 99.9% проблема в том, что у `mail.ru` для отправки почты теперь используется отдельный логин-пароль для сторонних приложений, а не тот же под которым вы входите в веб-почту.
Для создания логина-пароля для сторонних приложений логинитесь в веб-почту, идет в настройки вашего аккаунта, выбираете `"Пароль и безопасность"`, затем `"Пароли для внешних приложений"` и далее следуете инструкции от `mail.ru`.
После создания прописываете полученный логин-пароль в вашем коде.